# Does import run just once upon deployment or does it continue to import as time goes on?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, tokens

If github is hacked or disabled then the import would be corrupted.

```
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelincontracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just a way to import any solidity contract, when you deploy a contract all of your imports became the part of the your contract in other words you are deploying a flattened contract. In short your contracts has no link with github they will function as long as ethereum is functional.